How to show a guide/prompt overlay in Android
I am trying to a build a app that requests user for a scoped storage permission, and I want a guide/prompt to show on top of the system storage picker, like in the attached screenshot.
If anyone can point to link or let me know how can I build this, would be much appreciated.

